# Using web controller to print a report?

Tags: odoo-8

I need to print a report with two pages, one in portrait and another in landscape, for that I create two reports and used a web controller to merge them in one pdf file. But I got the following error message:

```
AccessError: ('AccessError', u"Database fetch misses ids (u'39') and has extra ids (39), may be caused by a type incoherence in a previous request")
```

How can I avoid this ?